# flutter: set exact width and height of the app's screen and restrict user ability to resize the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a flutter desktop app that has an exact `width` and `height` for the app's screen. So for example if `width = 400` and `height=800`, then the app's screen stay 400x800.

I would also like to restrict the user from resizing the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your dependencies:

```
window_size:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding
      path: plugins/window_size
```

Inside your `main.cpp` file find and change the Window size to:

```
Win32Window::Size size(400, 800);
```

And change your `main` to:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isLinux) {
    const mySize = Size(400, 800);
    setWindowMaxSize(mySize);
    setWindowMinSize(mySize);
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

You would need to `import 'dart:io'` to access `Platform` and

`import 'package:window_size/window_size.dart'` to access `setWindowMaxSize` and `setWindowMinSize`

Comment: The code works fine, however when I start the app, the sizes are different from the ones I want, but once i attempt resizing the screen resizes with the desired size, and only then it becomes impossible to resize. Also, do you know how to hide the top bar of the app? So that the user will not be able to close, minimize or go into windowed/full screen mode

Comment: For the first question I added an additional step that was missing, please check it out. About top bar question I haven't try that but I think you should probably add a new question just for that matter

Comment: will the main.cpp edit work on mac as well?

Comment: I think for mac the code I added in main should be enough, but if it's not you probably have to change the frame size in `MainFlutterWindow.swift` I don't really use flutter for mac sorry :(